# Cant figure out how to make the program detect that i entered a certain string and execute something based on that string

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a value for a: ");
a = scanner.nextDouble();

System.out.print(" Select side or angle: ");
side = scanner.next();

if (scanner.equals("side") ) {
    System.out.print("Enter a side value: ");
    b = scanner.nextDouble();
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
    System.out.println("The hypotenuse of the triangle is: " + hypotenuse);
}
```

Comment: You should use `side.equals("side")`

Comment: ^^ Right now you're saying if a Scanner object is equal to a string which is never true.